# Encountered following error when using Pandas groupby object filtering: TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, filtering

I have the following groupby object:

```
groupby=df.groupby('Product_1').mean().reset_index()
```

And then when I attempt to filter the data:

```
groupby.filter(lambda x: x['s_qual'].mean() > 3)
```

I recieve the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
C:\Users\A~1\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_48512/2738959142.py in <module>
----> 1 groupby.filter(lambda x: x['s_qual'].mean() > 3.)

~\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in filter(self, items, like, regex, axis)
   4980         if items is not None:
   4981             name = self._get_axis_name(axis)
-> 4982             return self.reindex(**{name: [r for r in items if r in labels]})
   4983         elif like:
   4984 

TypeError: 'function' object is not iterable
```

I am fairly new to coding, so if you can explain in simplified terms, it would be greatly appreciated.

I am unsure where I am going wrong here. Which function is it referencing that is not iterable?

Comment: Youre using [`DataFrame.filter`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html#pandas-dataframe-filter). As `items=` you supply lambda function, which is not iterable. Hence the error.

Comment: Hmm. I modeled my code after the official pandas documentation which uses a lambda function in a way nearly identical to my code. Maybe I am misunderstanding something here?

Comment: You probably mean `result = df.groupby('Product_1').filter(lambda x: x['s_qual'].mean() > 3)`